# How do i add the discount percentage to my products' page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I've been trying to add the discount percentage to each product's page **without** using any extensions. I am working with Magento 2.3.5. and I'm having a hard time finding any research that works with the same file path since im using my localhost. Can someone provide some assistance?

i wish to edit in the field referenced by this file path 
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navigate to
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

and add these code after

```
<span class="special-price">...</span>
```

add this code

```
<span class="sale" style="color: red">
    <?= /* @noEscape */'Save '.intval(
        (($priceModel->getValue()-$finalPriceModel->getValue())/$priceModel->getValue())*100
    ) .' %'?>
</span>
```